# How to get parameters of `req` in express node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two paramaters in my UI. One is a `file` and another is `dataObject`. In the utils, I have written code as :

```
importPlan: function (formData, planDTO) {
    return axios.post(`${importPlanAPIPath}`, planDTO, formData);
  }
```

In the router, I am sending this as :

```
router.post('/plans/importPlan/', planController.importPlan);
```

and in the controller, I have written the request as :

```
async importPlan(req, res, cb) {
    let plan,
      planDTO = req.body;

    const formData = new FormData(),
      file = req.files.file;

    formData.append('file', file.data);

    console.log('planDTO => ', planDTO);
    console.log(file.data, file.name);

    try {
      plan = await req.clients.planClient.importPlan(formData, planDTO);
    } catch (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }

    res.json(plan);
  }
```

In the `req.body`, I am getting the planDTO but I am not getting any `req.files` in the req. Also I am using `bodyparser` to parse the request. I am also using `busboybodyparser` for multipart/form-data.

Can Somebody please tell what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need  a node package that handles multipart/form-data https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer chek this

Comment: @AkramSaouri I am also using `busboybodyparser` for multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

yourparam is parameter name

```
    router.post('/plans/importPlan/:yourparam', planController.importPlan);

         async importPlan(req, res, cb) {

         var yourparam= req.params.yourparam;

            ..........

         res.json(plan);
         }
```

use this module for file  upload https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer